# Iframe refreshing through jquery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to refresh an `iframe` through jquery using :

```
 $("#iframeid").attr("src", $("#iframeid").attr("src"));
```

but it refreshing continuously like an infinite loop, can anybody tell me the problem?

Comment: Where is this code? In the iframe? in a loop?  Maybe show the other code involved in this process as well.

Comment: did you put this on iframe's load event?

Comment: this code is in the function , i am adding `data-role="button"` jquerymobile attribute to the anchor and this anchor tag is in the iframe so i refreshing iframe for applying attribute on the anchor tag

Comment: yes i am calling `Add function` from the `onload` event of the iframe and at the end of that `Add function` i am using the above mentioned code ( refreshing code )

Answer (score 1):

If you are attaching this code to the load event of the iframe then what you are seeing is the expected behaviour. What you are basically saying to the iframe is:

> Each time you get loaded,reload.

So I think you can see the looping behavior in that statement.

What you'll want to do is attach the reload code to some other event. A user click perhaps.

```
$("#refreshButton").on('click',function(){
  $("#iframeid").attr("src", $("#iframeid").attr("src"));
});
```

That way the iframe will only be reloaded when you want it to. You could also attach the reload to an interval to get periodic reloads:

```
var refreshInterval = setInterval(function(){
  $("#iframeid").attr("src", $("#iframeid").attr("src"));
},60000);
```

That code will refresh the iframe every 60000 milliseconds, or every minute (60 * 1000 = 60000).

Comment: Damn that comma is confusing. I was about to rant about "WHAT?! 60 ms is one minute? You be crazy!" But then I figured you were writing in another type method ...

Comment: @jam - you cracked me up `"iframe's are not Apple devices..."` :P

Comment: Glad I could be of service :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.
Refresh iframe using jquery.

```
$('#iframeID',window.parent.document).attr('src',$('#iframeID',window.parent.document).attr('src'));
```

and if you are working with same parent then

```
$('#iframeID',parent.document).attr('src',$('#iframeID',parent.document).attr('src'));
```